# Send Cap Issue with Distributed Marketing

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

Hoping someone could help here - we have Distributed Marketing and we have a send cap limit set for those sending emails through Core. That limit is at 1000 per month. We've noticed that some people are unable to send at the threshold limit. They are capped at 200 or 300. After adding the DM Activity report, and pulling the MCDM Send Cap log, I saw that the people are were capped did not send any where close to 1000 emails.

Also, I've confirmed what 'Send cap limits' were not changed and everyone should be able to send up to 1000 emails per month.

Has anyone had this issue with Distributed Marketing. Thank you in advance for any guidance here!

-Ashmeeta

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - We set a 30 day period in send settings. The DM activity is checking for total number of sends that occurred in the 30 day period minus the threshold, it's on a rolling basis. So, instead of the threshold replenishing at the beginning of the month say on the 1st, it's replenishing by the number of sends available from the threshold from the previous 30 day send.

This is not a practical calculation at all, and after speaking with support, seems like this might be something they look into resolving (fingers crossed they do).